# Use the redis lock

Tags: java, redis, locking, jedis

There is a business scenario: there are operations of adding, deleting and modifying, and no other operations can be performed during each operation. I want to use redis lock, and I would like to ask whether the key value of the lock can be set to a fixed String.

Will my idea solve the problem? Or there's a better way

Comment: Yes, Redis lock is a good solution to the problem. [ShedLock](https://github.com/lukas-krecan/ShedLock) is also commonly used.